# To use method from the main method java

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

This question is pretty specific for my problem, that is why I am creating a new question. The second method in this program is supposed to make a row of the number `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. The only problem I am having is that I don't know how to print this out in the main method.

```
public class Uppgift1_6a 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            int tal = Numberline(k);
            System.out.print(tal);
        }
    }

    public static int Numberline(int tal1) 
    {
        int tal = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            tal = tal1 + i;
        }
        return tal;
    }
}
```

Right now it prints out all the number from 11 to 19. And if I change it, it only prints out either 10 or 11.

Comment: Well. It is doing exactly what this code is telling it to print. Maybe you should clarify for yourself first (and then tell us) what exactly you **expect** this simple piece of code to print. In other words: provide a [mcve].

Comment: from question what I understand you want to print vertically then use System.out.println(tal); or if you want some kind of matrix then list of list or 2d array can be used

Comment: You could replace the code for `Numberline` with just `return tal1 + 10;` - I would take GhostCat's advice as well as slowly step through the code you have to determine why it's printing those values.  Looks like you want to string together the passed values rather than sum them..

Comment: As i said, i know this code is doing what I print it out to do, no shocker there! But I want to be able to command it from the main method. I want the things in the method printed out by a command from the main method. And I have to use the method Numberline.

Comment: And that's exactly what your code is doing, printing out `things` by a command executed from the main method/program entry point.

Comment: Yes but it wasn't printing it out in the order I wanted only the total sum. However, I have solved the problem now. Thanks

Comment: Don't understand people who down vote others who are trying to learn this language but might not be on their level yet. I saw the edits and they were nothing worth down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at the code:

```
public static int Numberline(int tal1)
{
    int tal = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        tal = tal1 + i;
    }
    return tal;
}
```

The `for` loop literally does absolutely nothing - you're only returning the final result. The final result is always exactly equal to `tal1 + 10`; again, what the `for` loop did up this point makes no difference. (I'd encourage you to step through the code with a debugger to convince yourself of that fact).

If you want it to print out the values as you're going through the `for` loop, you need to do something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    // You may need to modify this line too, depending on what values you want printed
    tal = tal1 + i;
    // Print the value here
    System.out.print(tal);
}
```

because the way you've written it it'll only print out the *final* value of `tal` (the one you returned).